# Nested struct access in C

Tags: c, struct, nested

I can't figure out why my code causes a segfault when I try the following give these structs:

```
typedef struct Vertex {
    int i;
    int color;
} vertex;

typedef struct Edge {
    vertex v1;
    vertex v2;
} edge;

typedef struct Node {
    vertex *v;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

node *nodehead = NULL;
```

code causing the issue here:

```
nodehead = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (nodehead == NULL) return -1;
nodehead->v->i = 10;
nodehead->next = NULL;
```

Maybe I'm missing something, most people had issues because they were trying to use the -> operator on an object.
It seems trying to assign the int to the nodehead->v->i field causes the issue.

Comment: assign something to nodehead->v before using it

Comment: The malloc allocates space for the two pointers inside struct Node; you do not have any memory allocated for those pointers to point to. That is, there is no struct Vertex behind nodehead->v

Comment: @Hogan Wrong.  He's not dereferncing `i`.  Look again.  The problem is that `v` is undefined, so an undefined pointer, `v`, is being dereferenced.  Not `i`.  Your version wouldn't even compile, since you're attempting `v.i` where `v` is a pointer.

Comment: @Hogan the `->` dereferences `v` (which _is_ a pointer) and not `i` (which is an integer). So the term `nodehead->v->i` is technically correct regarding the types (but the pointer variable member `v` is uninitialized, which leads to the crash)

Comment: @Hogan In general: When you write the expression `p->x`, then the "arrow" dereferences `p`, not `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no memory allocated for the member `vertex` of your `node`. Either allocate memory for it like this:

```
nodehead->v = malloc(sizeof(vertex));
```

before assigning the member `i`, or - probably even better - change your struct node to already include a full instance of vertex

```
typedef struct Node {
    vertex v;
    struct Node *next;
} node;
```

and access i like this:

```
nodehead->v.i = 10;
```

The latter method has the advantage, that you do not need to manage the memory for two objects, but only for the node itself. OTOH, if your vertices are used independently from the linked list, this method may not be appropriate; it depends on the context.

Comment: Thanks, I had just refactored my code and this was the issue that I didn't see at first.

Answer (score 0):

The line `nodehead->v->i = 10;` is what is giving you your problems.

You are trying to assign a value to `v`, however, no memory for `v` has been allocated. A solution would be to allocate memory to `v` before reaching this line.